# Codeigniter Templating (if / else if) in loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a loop of records which I am parsing through to a CI template and I need to run an if on a value in that loop but all I get is the string being output in the html can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Code:

```
{bond}
    <tr>
        <td>{bond_issuer}</td>
        <td>{bond_bond}</td>
        <td>
            {if bond_payment_frequency == 'A' }
            Annual
            {if:elseif bond_payment_frequency == 'SA'}
            Semi Annual
            {if:else}
            Quarterly
            {/if}
        </td>
        <td>{bond_coupon_pa}</td>
        <td>{bond_maturity_date}</td>
        <td>{bond_indicative_yield}</td>
        <td>{bond_asx_code}</td>
    </tr>
{/bond}
```

Output:

> {if bond_payment_frequency == 'A' } Annual {if:elseif
>   bond_payment_frequency == 'SA'} Semi Annual {if:else} Quarterly {/if}

Solution:

```
<?php foreach($bond as $b) {?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$b->bond_issuer;?></td>
        <td><?=$b->bond_bond;?></td>
        <td>
            <?php
                if($b->bond_payment_frequency === 'A') {
                    echo 'Annual';
                } elseif($b->bond_payment_frequency === 'SA') {
                    echo 'Semi Annual';
                } else {
                    echo 'Quarterly';
                };
            ?>
        </td>
        <td><?=$b->bond_coupon_pa;?></td>
        <td><?=$b->bond_maturity_date;?></td>
        <td><?=$b->bond_indicative_yield;?></td>
        <td><?=$b->bond_asx_code;?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I am using the standard CI one that ships I think

Comment: Hi!
Did you this well in your __contruct ()
$this->load->library('parse'); ?

Comment: Yes I am loading the parse library

Comment: Ok, and how do you call your template ?
Like this => $this->parser->parse('template', $data); or with a load->view() ?

Comment: I call it using the ```$this->parser->parse('template', $data);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding [the documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html), I don't think you can build conditions with the standard CI's Template Parser Class.

You can loop through arrays like you did with `{bond} [...] {/bond}`, but I don't think you can write `{if}` conditions.

Like the doc says :

> The Template Parser Class enables you to parse pseudo-variables contained within your view files. It can parse simple variables or variable tag pairs.
>
> [...]
>
> Also Note: The Template Parser Class is not a full-blown template parsing solution. We've kept it very lean on purpose in order to maintain maximum performance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I have redone the template to use straight PHP

Comment: Note that you can however use a "real" template engine like Smarty, that fits well with CI.